# Document.getElementByName for array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a loop over element in javascript ,
my html is:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="2">
```

and javascript is

```
window.onload = function() {
    var x = document.getElementsByName("menu");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i].type == "checkbox") {
            x[i].checked = true;
        }
    }

}
```

but no element was detected!!!!
try `alert(x.length)` and you seen 0!!

Comment: Why would it be detected??? `menu` isn't the name!!!!

Comment: @BhojendraNepal - What if the OP needs to collect the checkbox values in a language like PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element name is `menu[]`, just like it says in the HTML source.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var x = document.getElementsByName("menu[]"), i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i].type == "checkbox") {
            x[i].checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="2">
<p>All checkboxes named <b>menu[]</b> have been checked.</p>
```

HTML does not care about the square brackets. They have no meaning, they are just like letters.

The fact that, for example, PHP treats them specially is nothing that HTML is concerned with.

**P.S.** Don't forget to declare your loop counter `i`, otherwise it will be global, and you don't want a global loop counter.

Comment: Of course it works. Run the code snippet in my answer if you don't believe it.